# Angular cli stuck on new Win10

Tags: node.js, angular

I have fresh win10 64bit installed and I am trying to setup the nodejs environment. After installation of the latest node I am running `npm install -g @angular/cli`
 however the installation stuck with error message `fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule punycode@2.1.1 checking installable status`
I have disabled windows defender but it seems that the installation doesn't work.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

`npm -v : 6.4.1
node -v: 10.12.0`

So far i have tried to install with cmd and powershell with and without admin rights.

Comment: Have you tried to run that command using a terminal with admin privileges?

Comment: yea... cmd and powershel .. with the same result

Comment: Can you install local? (no `-g`) into an app's directory?

Comment: no , the installation stops with different error: `fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule co@4.6.0 checking installable status`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: nope .. just typical home broadband connection

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried using Yarn instead of npm? https://yarnpkg.com/en/

Comment: yes i have .. it installs without any issue, but i never used before and would prefer npm for consistency

Comment: can you try with Node 8.12.0 cause this is the stable and currently recommended to use for windows.

Comment: Sounds like the npm installation might have been corrupted. I'm using Node 10.12 and other versions via nvm on Windows 10 without issue.

Comment: i had tried all versions, from the latest to version 7, including of cours 8.12

Comment: i really cannot see how it can be corrupted as i did installation many times following the well known process.